# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android 9.0

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I have strange issue in production only in Android 9.0, the app in production very long time and this issue starts in Android 9.0

> Process: com.ae.paris10, PID: 18804
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=984; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=1024
>   at
>   java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1719)
>   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:487)
>   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)

```
   private void copyStyleWithNewTilesPath() throws IOException {

        InputStream myinput = getContext()
                .getAssets().open("styleParis.json");


        String outfilename = "/data/data/" + Config.APPLICATION_ID + "/databases/styleParis.json";


        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {

            String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

            if (str.contains("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf")) {
  buffer = str.replace("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf", "file://" + obbPath + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf").getBytes("UTF-8");
            }

            myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length); <<--- EXCEPTION HERE <<-----------
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }
```

I don't really understand what happens since the in FileOutputStream is Java and Android framework.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: Exception questions need to include the full stack trace at least up to the level of something in your code.  Also indicate which line of your source code is the first mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: ```buffer = str.replace("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf", "file://" + obbPath + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf").getBytes("UTF-8");``` is replacing the ```byte``` array, have you debugged and checked the length of ```buffer``` if the condition is true?

Comment: i will check, but why it may change on Android 9.0

Comment: If you replace the buffer in one iteration of the while, things may get messy at the top of **the next when you try to read into something that is no longer your allocated buffer**.  Probably what you want to do is rather than replace the buffer, just write the altered output directly in the if condition and otherwise write the buffer in the else...

Comment: And in the case of the modification, you need to write the modified length, not the original length.

Comment: The length will be change because you replaced the original text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will resolve your problem:

```
if (str.contains("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"))
    myoutput.write(str.replace("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf", "file://" + obbPath + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf").getBytes("UTF-8"));
else
    myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
```

Comment: it work thank! but i would like to know why my code worked in al androidl api's <28

Comment: @PavelPoley Maybe this `if` never executed before!

Comment: not possible, it is 1 year in production without this 'if' the map in the app doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
if (str.contains("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"))
    // write(byte[] b) :: Writes b.length bytes from the specified byte array to myoutput. 
    myoutput.write(str.replace("file://mnt/obb/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf", "file://" + obbPath + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf").getBytes("UTF-8"));
else
    myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
```